# Understanding threads in C and how to sort with them

Tags: c++, multithreading, mergesort

I have a question about threads and was wondering if someone could help me out.
So, I was studying this code and got confused on how I could change the number of threads being used:

```
// multi-threading
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>

// number of elements in array
#define MAX 20

// number of threads
#define THREAD_MAX 4

using namespace std;

// array of size MAX
int a[MAX];
int part = 0;

// merge function for merging two parts
void merge(int low, int mid, int high)
{
    int* left = new int[mid - low + 1];
    int* right = new int[high - mid];

    // n1 is size of left part and n2 is size
    // of right part
    int n1 = mid - low + 1, n2 = high - mid, i, j;

    // storing values in left part
    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        left[i] = a[i + low];

    // storing values in right part
    for (i = 0; i < n2; i++)
        right[i] = a[i + mid + 1];

    int k = low;
    i = j = 0;

    // merge left and right in ascending order
    while (i < n1 && j < n2) {
        if (left[i] <= right[j])
            a[k++] = left[i++];
        else
            a[k++] = right[j++];
    }

    // insert remaining values from left
    while (i < n1) {
        a[k++] = left[i++];
    }

    // insert remaining values from right
    while (j < n2) {
        a[k++] = right[j++];
    }
}

// merge sort function
void merge_sort(int low, int high)
{
    // calculating mid point of array
    int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
    if (low < high) {

        // calling first half
        merge_sort(low, mid);

        // calling second half
        merge_sort(mid + 1, high);

        // merging the two halves
        merge(low, mid, high);
    }
}

// thread function for multi-threading
void* merge_sort(void* arg)
{
    // which part out of 4 parts
    int thread_part = part++;

    // calculating low and high
    int low = thread_part * (MAX / 4);
    int high = (thread_part + 1) * (MAX / 4) - 1;

    // evaluating mid point
    int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
    if (low < high) {
        merge_sort(low, mid);
        merge_sort(mid + 1, high);
        merge(low, mid, high);
    }
}

// Driver Code
int main()
{
    // generating random values in array
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
        a[i] = rand() % 100;

    // t1 and t2 for calculating time for
    // merge sort
    clock_t t1, t2;

    t1 = clock();
    pthread_t threads[THREAD_MAX];

    // creating 4 threads
    for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_MAX; i++)
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, merge_sort,
                                        (void*)NULL);

    // joining all 4 threads
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
```

This part below is specially hard because I'm not sure what these "(MAX / 2, MAX/2 + (MAX-1-MAX/2)/2, MAX - 1);" actually work. How can I make, for example, 2 or 8 threads?

```
    // merging the final 4 parts
    merge(0, (MAX / 2 - 1) / 2, MAX / 2 - 1);
    merge(MAX / 2, MAX/2 + (MAX-1-MAX/2)/2, MAX - 1);
    merge(0, (MAX - 1)/2, MAX - 1);

    t2 = clock();

    // displaying sorted array
    cout << "Sorted array: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
        cout << a[i] << " ";

    // time taken by merge sort in seconds
    cout << "Time taken: " << (t2 - t1) /
            (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

How do we proceed in this situation?

Thanks!

Comment: This is C++, not C.

Comment: When it says `// number of threads` `#define THREAD_MAX 4` have you tried changing the number 4?

Comment: @user253751 and that's all? don't i have to make more changes in the code to make it work with a different number of threads?

Comment: Yes, you do need to make other changes, since there's at least one place in the code where the number 4 was used instead of `THREAD_MAX`

Comment: @user3386109 Alright, makes sense. But then where it is written " merging the final 4 parts" doesn't change? How that works?

Comment: Each thread gets a subarray (array0, array1, array2, array3) to sort. After all the threads finish, `main` needs to merge all of the subarrays. So `main` merges array0 with array1, and array2 with array3. Then it merges those two arrays to create the final result. With more threads, you have more sorted subarrays for `main` to merge.

Comment: @user3386109 I think i got it. So no changes are needed here: ```merge(0, (MAX / 2 - 1) / 2, MAX / 2 - 1);
    merge(MAX / 2, MAX/2 + (MAX-1-MAX/2)/2, MAX - 1);
    merge(0, (MAX - 1)/2, MAX - 1);``` Another question, im trying to make it work in C, but am having trouble converting this function: void merge(int low, int mid, int high). It has some declarations as new int and stuff that I don't know how to use. What should i change?

Comment: C uses `malloc` and `free` instead of `new` and `delete`. When you think of threads, make sure you read [5 Big Fat Reasons Mutexes Suck, Big Time](https://accu.org/var/uploads/journals/Overload149.pdf)

Comment: You are working from a sad code base.  If you want to learn, you should find better examples; this is a poorly implemented mess.   That, in itself, has learning value, but only when you are more familiar with this topic.  The line: int thread_part = part++;  is a case in point.  An obvious race condition, whose existence calls into question the rest of the implementation.

Comment: I wrote an example of a somewhat optimized multi-threaded merge sort using Windows native threads in [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/148025). After sorting the 4 parts, thread 0 is used to merge the first 2 parts, and thread 2 is used to merge the second 2 parts, then thread 0 merges the two merged arrays. It's hard coded for 4 threads, but doesn't take much to change to 8 threads.